# ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager

Tags: database, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework v5;
I am view link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectstatemanager.aspx
But in this code
*myDbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(objClass, EntityState.Modified);*
not have property ObjectStateManager. 
Where it is property? Or how resolve it problem?

Comment: You don't have an `ObjectContext`, you have a `DbContext`. They're not the same thing, and you shouldn't be needing the `ObjectContext` documentation. The `DbContext` method is slightly different, but I'll not post this as an answer, as I don't have the precise details ready right now.

Answer (score 1):

DbContext API does this differently:

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You must follow [documentation for API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696142%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) you are using.